# Adding layout file to class (Java Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, class, android-layout

When adding an (empty activity), the class generates with the appropriate layout file but in the `setContentview(R.layout.activity_home)` it gives an error.

This is my (empty) class:

```
package com.test.learnlogin;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    }

}
```

And this is the layout file to refer to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you add what exact error is showing up on the setContentView line??

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the name  `activity_home` inside `setContentView` is of red color.

if yes and  you are sure that `activity_home` file exists in `Res`>`Layout` then please `Restart` Your `Android Studio`, that All

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to import R to remove that error.

```
import com.test.R // assuming your_package_name=com.test
```

at the top.